# Simple JNI call not working

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

In my C++ side I have :

```
extern "C" {
      JNIEXPORT void JNICALL test(JNIEnv*, jobject){}
}
```

My Acivity has a declared method :

```
public native void test();
```

However when I call test I get the error native method not found. What's the problem ?

Comment: Your activity's full class name should be part of that export. A hunt for `"[java] [jni] [android] native method not found"` will proffer a *wealth* of information. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100542/native-method-not-found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JNI is not looking for a function `test`. The name it looks for is of the form `Java_packagename_classname_functionname`. For example, if your class is

```
package your.package;

public class Activity {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("your_library");
  }

  public native void test();
}
```

Then your library has to contain a function

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_your_package_Activity_test(JNIEnv *, jobject) { }
```

...assuming that `test` is not overloaded. If `test` is overloaded, use the `javah` program to generate a header for you because you don't want to do that manually.

```
javah your.package.Activity
```

will generate a file `your_package_Activity.h` that contains the function signatures you need. Note that this requires the `Activity` class to be compiled, i.e., there has to be a file `your/package/Activity.class` in the class path.

Comment: Exactly, that was the problem